# What is the best order of columns on a compound index?

Tags: mysql, index, innodb

I have a series of small 'attribute' tables (innodb) with this structure:

```
uuid 
name (TEXT)
organisation_id (INT)
```

In my application, when users add a new attribute, I am first performing a lookup if it already exists, `SELECT * WHERE name = '?' AND organisation_id = '?'`

What would the optimal index setup be?

Bonus:

I am also displaying all attributes from an organisation so often just querying the table by organisation_id, do I need a separate independent key on the organisation_id column or will the compound be ok for this too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, the order of the columns in an index is very important. Searching over an **INT** is faster than search on a **string(VARCHAR)**. So an index on **(organisation_id, name)** would be better than that on **(name, organisation_id)**.

If a **WHERE clause** satisfies the **prefix** an INDEX then that INDEX is used. So no need for a separate index on organisation_id. The existing index will take care of it.

Comment: I agree on the index, but for a different reason. Major benefit with that index is that sometime organisation_id alone is used in predicate.

Comment: Wrong.  Either order is equally good.  Think of it this way:  The two columns are concatenated, then that becomes the key.

Comment: MySQL can use multiple-column indexes for queries that test all the columns in the index, or queries that test just the first column, the first two columns, the first three columns, and so on. If you specify the columns in the right order in the index definition, a single composite index can speed up several kinds of queries on the same table.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Answer (score 1):

```
name (TEXT)
```

`TEXT` columns are not indexable.  There is a way to do a prefix -- `INDEX(name(30))`, but it is rarely useful.

Instead, change it to a suitably sized `VARCHAR`, which can be indexed (up to some limit).

Once you change to `VARCHAR`, either of these will work equally well:

```
INDEX(name, organization_id)
INDEX(organization_id, name)
```

If you have other queries, they may guide you into which would be more useful.

"a lookup if it already exists" --  Consider whether IODKU would be appropriate.

More discussion here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239658/higher-cardinality-column-first-in-an-index-when-involving-a-range